# how to use loop to deleteBackward()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, custom-keyboard, textdocumentproxy

I want to delete 5 characters in a string, so I plan to use a loop to do that.
but actually code not report any error, but still, I can only delete one character

```
var i = Int()
repeat {
    proxy.deleteBackward(); 
    i = i+1
} while i<5
```

Comment: As far as i understood u want to remove the last 5 characters of a string. u can use ```your_string.dropLast(5)```

Comment: Sure, I want to delete the last 5 character, thanks to clarify that for me1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove last 5 characters of your string , use

```
myString.dropLast(5)
```

if you want to run your deleteBackward() method 5 times, use like this

```
var i = 0
        while i<5 {
            proxy.deleteBackward()
           i += 1
        }
```